# Image Compression in MATLAB/ Octave

Tags: image, matlab, compression, octave, svd

I am new learner of MATLAB/ Octave programming, I have to do an assignment related to image compression in MATLAB/ Octave. Hereby, I am going to attach my assignment's statement. I have done some coding in Octave, but failed. I have tried many times but no progress. Please help me to do this assignment.

Question: You are required to take at least 5 images with different resolutions and use SVD for image compression. For each image:

- How many modes do you need for the compressed color (RGB) image to look good?
- How much more efficient are your nice compressed images in terms of storage space?

Here I am going to attach the code which I have tried but no progress.

```
clear all;
close all;
f1= @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data);
f2= @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data);
A = imread("group.jpg");
imwrite(A, "new.jpg");
%Im = rgb2gray(A);
%figure, imshow(A);
J= blockproc (A, [8 8],f1);
depth= find(abs(J) <150);
J(depth)= zeros(size(depth));
K= blockproc(J, [8 8], f2)/255;
figure, imshow(K);
imwrite(K, "new1.jpg");
compression_ratio= numel(J)/numel(depth)
```

Comment: "I have tried many times but no progress." So why don't you show one of your attempts, and discuss what the problems with it are? That way, you'll have a more focussed and useful question. As it stands now, your question reads "please do my homework for me", which is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `
clear all;

close all;

f1= @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data);

f2= @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data);

A = imread("group.jpg");

imwrite(A, "new.jpg");

%Im = rgb2gray(A);

%figure, imshow(A);

J= blockproc (A, [8 8],f1);

depth= find(abs(J) <150);

J(depth)= zeros(size(depth));

K= blockproc(J, [8 8], f2)/255;

figure, imshow(K);

imwrite(K, "new1.jpg");

compression_ratio= numel(J)/numel(depth)
`

Comment: Above is the code, which i have tried but failed.

Comment: Usman, please [edit] your question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can you help me with it?